# Querying azure mobile services with javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I am working on a mobile application using apache cordova.. I have a javascript file that reads data from an azure mobile service and persists it onto the local SQLITE database..

i have a function that is meant to query the azure mobile service but it gives me an error -"cannot read propert 'take' of undefinedType". The function is as follows

```
function refreshQuestionsTable() {
        alert("questions refreshing");
     var query = QuestionsTable.take(100).read().done(function (results) {
        alert(results.length); //see how many records were returned
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    alert(results[i].question); //display the question returned
    commitQuestions(results[i].question_id, results[i].client_ref, results[i].question_set, results[i].question_dept, results[i].question, results[i].question_branch, null);

        }

    },function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });  

}
```

Comment: Where is the variable `QuestionsTable` defined?

Comment: Agreed here - there isn't enough information in the question to determine where you are going wrong, but I suspect it's in the definition of QuestionsTable.  Check out the Azure Mobile Service Cordova SDK: https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-services-cordova

Comment: the defination of questionsTable is  as follows                                                 var MobileServiceClient = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;
var client = new MobileServiceClient('https://feedbackmaster.azure-mobile.net/', 'oLMEOExWGFolBhpyYpTFkqvKuLNlyL91');
var QuestionsTable = client.getTable('client_questions');

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your client instantiation piece is wrong.

`var client = new MobileServiceClient('feedbackmaster.azure-mobile.net/', 'oLMEOExWGFolBhpyYpTFkqvKuLNlyL91');`

You had a ';' at the end of your URL for some reason. You should also do a `.where()` clause that is universally true. Take should work off of that.